# How to disable CSS in Browser for testing purposes

Tags: html, css, browser

Is there any way I can disable all external CSS in a browser (Firefox, Chrome...)?

When using slower internet connection, sometimes only the bare HTML is loaded by the browser without the CSS info. It looks like the page has been laid raw on the screen. You would have noticed this with StackOverflow too.

I want to make sure that my web page shows up OK even if the CSS files are not loaded.

I didn't mean I want to convert external CSS to inline. But I want a way to explicitly disable all CSS from the browser so that I can reposition my elements in a better, readable way.

I know I can remove the <link rel='stylesheet'> entries, but what if I have a lot of linked pages?

Comment: This is a very good question. As it appears, for example, Chrome does not allow to "turn off" the author style sheets in a way that is acceptable for a standard user. This makes Chrome not conform to CSS 2.1, as can be seen in Chapter 3.2.6 of the spec, where it is said, that "The UA must allow the user to turn off the influence of author style sheets." The same could be true for other browsers that do not allow it natively.

Comment: right-click the page, select **Inspect** from the context menu, locate the `<head>` tag, right-click, and pick **Delete element**.

Comment: Since at least 2017, Firefox has buttons to turn off individual css files *and* inline style sheets, via the built-in dev tools, as described below in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238311

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The Web Developer plugin for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) is able to do this

Once you have installed the plugin the option is available in the CSS menu. For example, `CSS > Disable Styles > Disable All Styles`

[image]

Alternatively with the developer toolbar enabled you can press `Alt+Shift+A`.

Comment: Can you specify how to do it there?

Comment: Thanks... Does Firebug have this feature?

Comment: YOu can also use Lynx browser. See my comments down below.

Comment: @ToadyMores I don't think Lynx will serve the purpose. See my comment under your answer.

Comment: Firebug allows you to selectively disable/enable some selectors and live edit the existing CSS, so in a sense it is possible. For your purpose the Web Developer plugin seems more appropriate though, there you have the option to disable all CSS or specific stylesheets, amongst other useful tools for assessing the accessibility of a site for older/mobile browsers.

Comment: This answer doesn't have any information on *how* to do it, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: Annoying that the styles returns when reloading the page. I would like to skip the styles already during load.

Comment: The Paciello Group has a similar Toolbar that works in IE 9/10/11. http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/wat/

Comment: Seems to no longer work for Chrome

Answer (score 85):

In Chrome/Chromium you can do this in the developer console.

1. Bring up the developer console by either ctrl-shift-j or Menu->Tools->Developer Console.
2. Within the developer console browse to the Sources tab.
3. In the top-left corner of this tab is an icon with a disclosure triangle. Click on it.
4. Browse to <domain>→css→<css file you want to eliminate>
5. Highlight all of the text and hit delete.
6. Rinse and repeat for each stylesheet you want to disable.

Comment: If you have a lot of sources and want to find where CSS has been nested, start on the Network tab and filter the responses to just include Stylesheets.  Then right click on the response and click "Open in sources panel". Then Ctrl + A, Del

Comment: Seems all different now in 2021. Too bad. And/or is only discussing external .css files.

Answer (score 25):

Firefox (Win and Mac)

- Via the menu toolbar, choose: "View" > "Page Style" > "No Style"
- Via the Web Developer Toolbar, choose: "CSS" > "Disable Styles" > "All Styles"

If the Web Dev Toolbar is installed, people can use this keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Mac) and <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Win)

- Safari (Mac): Via the menu toolbar, choose "Develop" > "Disable
  Styles"
- Opera (Win): Via the menu, choose "Page" > "Style" > "User Mode"
- Chrome (Win): Via the gear icon, choose the "CSS" tab > "Disable All
  Styles"
- Internet Explorer 8: Via the menu toolbar, choose "View" > "Style" >
  "No Style"
- Internet Explorer 7: via the IE Developer Toolbar menu: Disable > All
  CSS
- Internet Explorer 6: Via the Web Accessibility Toolbar, choose "CSS" > "Disable CSS"

Comment: Chrome (Win): this option no longer seems to exist; @David Baucum's answer below does work.

Answer (score 21):

This script works for me (hat tip to scrappedcola)

```
var el=document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){if (el[i].getAttribute("type")=="text/css") el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]); };
```

inline style stays intact, though

Comment: `$('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove()` achieves the same, if has jQuery. From https://twitter.com/janlelis/status/433250838757126146.

Comment: This is awesome,just hit F12 in chrome, browse to console hit paste and enter.

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on scrappedocola/renergy's idea, you can turn the [JavaScript into a bookmarklet](http://www.dev-hq.net/posts/1--create-javascript-bookmarklet) that executes against the `javascript:` uri so the code can be re-used easily across multiple pages without having to open up the dev tools or keep anything on your clipboard.

Just run the following snippet and drag the link to your bookmarks/favorites bar:

```html
<a href="javascript: var el = document.querySelectorAll('style,link');
         for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
           el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]); 
         };">
  Remove Styles 
</a>
```

- I would avoid looping through the thousands of elements on a page with `getElementsByTagName('*')` and have to check and act on each individually.
- I would avoid relying on jQuery existing on the page with `$('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove()` when the extra javascript is not overwhelmingly cumbersome.

Comment: That's the fastest way to do it, I like that method.

Comment: To clear inline CSS: `document.querySelectorAll('*[style]').forEach((e)=>e.removeAttribute('style'));` Only iterates through elements with existing `style` attributes.

Answer (score 13):

### Delete `<head>` with a bookmarklet

For pages that rely on external CSS (most pages nowadays) you can delete the `head` element:

```js
document.querySelector("head").remove();
```

Usage: right-click the page (in Chrome/Firefox), select *Inspect*, paste the code above in the devtools console and press *Enter*.

A bookmarklet version of the same code that you can paste as the URL of a bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelector("head").remove();})()
```

Now clicking the bookmark in your Bookmarks bar will (hopefully) strip all the css stylesheets.

### Delete `<head>` via devtools

Another way to achieve it is to right-click the page (in Chrome/Firefox), select <kbd>Inspect</kbd>, in devtools panel, Elements tab select the `<head>` tag (see screenshot), right-click it, and pick <kbd>Delete element</kbd>:

[image: delete the head tag]

> Note: Removing the head will not work for pages that use inline styles.

### Safari-only solution

If you happen to use Safari on MacOS then:

1. Open Safari Preferences (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and in the **Advanced** tab enable the checkbox "Show Develop menu in menu bar".
2. Now under the **Develop** menu you will find a *Disable Styles* option.

### Custom bookmarklet to 'fix' all styles

For making any page readable and adjust it to your liking you can also use a custom bookmarklet that will set your own preferred styling:

```js
(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled = true;
    }
    all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        el = all[i];
        el.style.cssText = '';
        el.style.width = '';
        el.style.padding = '.5em';
        el.style.margin = '.3em';
        el.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        el.style.color = '#000';
    }
})()
```

Minified version of the bookmarklet that you can paste as URL of a bookmark in your browser:

```js
javascript:(function(){for(i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++){document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled=true;}
all=document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){el=all[i];el.style.cssText='';el.style.width='';el.style.padding='4px';el.style.margin='3px';el.style.backgroundImage='none';el.style.backgroundColor='#fff';el.style.color='#000';}})()
```

> <sup>NOTE: You can test it on this page by pasting the code above into the browser address bar and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> — make sure you prepend `javascript:` at the beginning since most browsers will automatically strip it when you copy it to the clipboard (for security reasons).</sup>

**NOTE**: Bookmarklets will not work on page content inside frames (`<frame>` and `<iframe>` elements) and also might not work on sites that define strict CSP's (content-security-policy rules) which is the case with stackoverflow and related sites. The code will still work when run from devtools console or from the address bar with the `javascript:` prefix.

Answer (score 10):

Install Adblock Plus, then add `*.css` rule in Filters options (custom filters tab). The method affect only on **external stylesheets**. It doesn't turn off inline styles.

> Disable all external CSS

This method does exactly what you asked.

Comment: This is the only solution that still works when you reload the page. Unfortunately, you can't test it with ads.

Comment: @sinuhepop You can disable all filter lists in ABP. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Sure! I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to install adBlock when DevTools do this out of the box? What advantage does AdBlock solution bring to the table?

Answer (score 7):

As no one else mentioned this possibility. You can also disable any resources in Chrome from the `DevTools > Network request blocking`. This gives you much more granularity as well as ease of use.

It is likely to be hidden before the first use. Just press `Command + shift + P` (I presume it's `ctrl + shift + P` on Linux/Win) in the Devtools and type `network request blocking`.

[image]

You can then define what resources you want to block, ie. `*.css` and/or `*.js` and click on `Enable network request blocking` checkbox.

[image]

Reload to load the page without the specified resources.

Comment: This is the only sane answer in 2022 and should be upvoted.

Comment: I think this solution won't work for inline css included in html files with the style tag.

Comment: @Adrian you're absolutely right about that. However, the question is specifically about external CSS.

> Is there any way I can disable all external CSS in a browser (Firefox, Chrome...)?

Answer (score 5):

As most answers seem to be pretty old here, referencing menu items I can't seem to find in the current versions of popular browsers, here's how to do it in the current version in Firefox Developer Edition:

- Open Developer Tools (`CTRL + SHIFT + I`)
- Select the Style Editor tab
- There you should see all sources of CSS in your document. You can disable each of them by clicking the eye icon next to them.

[image: White eye icon = enabled; Gray eye icon = disabled]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve @David Baucum's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892877/426193) in fewer steps:

1. Right click -> inspect element
2. Click on the stylesheet's name that affect your element (just on the right side of the declaration)
3. Highlight all of the text and hit delete.

It could be handier in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

you can block any request (even for a single css file) from inspector with the following:
 
    **Right click > block request URL**
 
without disabling other css files  > https://umaar.com/dev-tips/68-block-requests/ 
It's a standard inspector feature, no plugins or tricks needed

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want any plugin or other stuffs, We can use the document.styleSheets to disable/enable the css.

// code to disable all the css

```
for (const item in document.styleSheets) {
  document.styleSheets[item].disabled=true;
}
```

If you use chrome, you can create a function and add to your snippets. So that you can use the console to enable/disable the css for any sites.

// Snippets -> DisableCSS

```
function disableCss(value = true){
  for (const item in document.styleSheets) {
    document.styleSheets[item].disabled=value;
  }  
}
```

// in console

```
disableCss() // by default is disable
disableCss(false) // to enable
```

Comment: Change the `disabled=false` with a `disabled=true` and you will have a lot of upvotes ;)

Comment: This is the best answer (for me, or anyone wanting to add only extensions they REALLY need). You can take this answer and make two bookmarklets, CSSoFF and CSSoN, then with no extension you have a 1-click on/off for CSS on any page, with no need to use the console (for that part of your work).

Answer (score 2):

I tried in Chrome Developer tools and the method is valid only if the CSS are included as external files and it won't work for inline styles.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('link'), (element)=>element.remove());
```

Or

```
var linkElements = document.querySelectorAll('link');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(linkElements, (element)=>element.remove());
```

Explanations

1. `document.querySelectorAll('link')` gets all the link nodes. This will return array of DOM elements. Note that this is not Array object of javascript.
2. `Array.prototype.forEach.call(linkElements` loops through the link elements
3. `element.remove()` removes the element from the DOM

Resulting in plain HTML page

Comment: Alternatively, for inline styles: `document.querySelectorAll("style").forEach((e)=>(e.remove()))`

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome:

1. Open Dev Tools (inspect element).
2. Go to "network" tab.
3. Select any css file and right-click: "Block request url".
4. Go to the inspector´s footer to a "networking request blocking" tab.
5. Click on plus icon, and add some pattern like "*.css".
6. Reload the webpage.

This process allow to disable all css files at once.

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox, the simplest way is via the menu command View > Page Style > No Style. But this also switches off the effects of some presentational HTML markup. So using plugins as suggested by @JoelKuiper is usually better; they give more flexibility (e.g., switching off just some style sheets).

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser's (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) Dev Tools (`F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+J`).

Then switch to the `Console` tab and paste this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach((el)=>(el.remove()));document.querySelectorAll('[style]').forEach((el)=>(el.removeAttribute('style')));
```

Hit `Enter` and enjoy the complitely unstyled website!

Answer (score 0):

While inspecting HTML with the Browser Development tool you prefer (eg Chrome Devtools) find the `<head>` element and delete it at all.

Notice that this **will also remove js** but for me it is **the fastest way to get** the page **naked**.

Answer (score 0):

All the suggested answers merely eliminate the css for that page load. Depending on your use-case, you may wish to not load the css at all:

Chrome Dev Tools > Network Tab > Right click on stylesheet in question > block request url

Comment: Also needed is "how to turn off CSS for the entire browser session, no matter how many sites or windows or tabs we open."

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's easier than you think. In any browsers press F12 to bring up the debug console. This works for IE, Firefox, and Chrome. Not sure about Opera. Then comment out the CSS in the element windows. That's it.

Comment: Lynx will also ignore all other styling. That's not desired here.