# Is there anyway I can get simple HTML of a page but with images and links?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

With this query:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=aristotle&redirects=true

I get the page in its simplest HTML form. Really basic stuff. 
But what I really want is to also get the images and links in that page.

I've also tried other options ([action=parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=xml&page=aristotle&prop=text&contentformat=text%2Fplain) and [action=query](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=aristotle)), but they return too much overhead in the form of css styles or unparsed response.

Can I achieve simple HTML content with images and links?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that disabling the CSS on the page should do what I think it is you are asking for.

In Chrome you can do this in the developer console:

1. Bring up the developer console by either hitting F12 or navigating to it 
   Menu --> More Tools --> Developer Console.
2. Within the developer console browse to the Sources tab. In the top-left corner of this tab is an icon with a left facing arrow. Click on it.
3. Browse to the css file you want to eliminate. Start at the Network layer and work down, seems to work best. Highlight all of the text and hit delete.
4. Remove stylesheets until getting the result you want.

This stackoverflow article has other options as well as this:
[How to disable CSS in Browser for testing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes)

Comment: pinmonkeyiii, maybe it's my fault for not making it clear that I'm looking for a simplified API call.