# How can I turn off features of css in chrome for testing e.g. css grid

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

I'm trying to see how my app will look when css grid isn't available.  Is it possible to turn off properties like css grid inside of the chrome or canary?

Comment: You can absolutely disable CSS rules from the F12 Inspector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable CSS in Browser for testing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes)

Comment: @ObsidianAge it's not about rule, but about a feature ... if it was a rule then we can simply comment the CSS file. He want to see what the code will look if there is not support of css-grid

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

Comment: Just uncheck the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSS Feature Toggles](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-feature-toggles/aeinmfddnniiloadoappmdnffcbffnjg) plugin for Chrome can do this.  It adds a tab in the developer toolbox with checkboxes for various CSS features that are popular for browsers to not implement, like Grid:

[image]

Checking the relevant box will disable the respective feature.

Comment: No.  This is not the answer.  This extension is INCREDIBLY out of date and MANY features which we need to disable for testing are not accessible with this extension such as "aspect-ratio" and MUCH MORE.  Please, this is NOT the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Download an older version of Chrome that doesn't support this feature after checking it on https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside.

Comment: You would be surprised how difficult it is to install old versions of browsers.  I lost about 48 hours of my life trying to figure out how to do this.  There is no easy solution.  Every browser distro forces you to use their current stable release.

Answer (score -3):

Just comment out CSS Grid.

```
/* .container { display: grid; } */
```

Or uncheck the rule in dev tools.

Chrome will then ignore all grid properties, just like a browser would that lacks support for the feature.