# Is it possible to step through the loading of each CSS file?

Tags: html, css, browser, google-chrome-devtools, rendering

I do not have access to the code. I want to load a page and stop it prior to every CSS file that is loaded. Is this possible in DevTools or is there another resource?

Answer (score 0):

The Web Developer plugin for Firefox and Chrome is able to do this

Once you have installed the plugin the option is available in the CSS menu. For example, CSS > Disable Styles > Disable All Styles

Check this out for more details: [How to disable CSS in Browser for testing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes)

Comment: This is the link for the chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

Comment: The problem, is more related to synchronous vs asynchronous calls, so it isn't that I want to enable/disable styling... it is that on render, i want to stop before each css file is loaded.

Comment: Then maybe you can try blocking requests like this: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/68-block-requests/